# If scrolled 300 px change background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a fixed nav that is grey. But I want it to change colour to white if you have scrolled 300 px.

Demo: http://eldecosmetics.com/blogs/vemund 
Password: Pruget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
   var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
   var nav = document.getElementById('scroll-nav');
   if (scrollTop >= 300) {
       nav.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
   } else {
       nav.style.backgroundColor = '#f9f7f1';
   }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This solved it easily and made the whole page look cool.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
    var top = this.scrollY;
    if(top > 300) {
      // Do Something
    }
    else {
      // Rollback to previous state?
    }
}, false);
```

You can do it like that